# Copying selected files

Tags: linux

How to copy selected files from a list to a new name?

```
mynumber#P#Apr10.ARZ
mynumber#P#Aug10.ARZ
mynumber#P#Dec10.ARZ
mynumber.frm
mynumber.par
```

I want to copy all the files starting with the word "mynumber" with a different name. So the new list will look something like this...

```
mynumber#P#Apr10.ARZ
mynumber#P#Aug10.ARZ
mynumber#P#Dec10.ARZ
mynumber.frm
mynumber.par
yournumber#P#Apr10.ARZ
yournumber#P#Aug10.ARZ
yournumber#P#Dec10.ARZ
yournumber.frm
yournumber.par
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `find /var/lib/mysql/test/ -name "Table1.*"`
do
cp $i `dirname $i`'/test'`basename $i`
done
```

duplicate a table Table1 by coping the files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `pyRenamer`.  It should be in your distribution's repository.  Very useful for renaming based on all sorts of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general Idea ::

temp=`ls mynumber*`

for i in $temp

do

bak=`echo $i | sed 's/mynumber/yournumber/'`

cp $i $bak

done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in mynumber*; do
    cp -- "$i" "your${i:2}"
done
```

Tested and working against your example filenames, and it will work on any filename -- even those containing spaces.